# Cannot create D2D1 device

Tags: c++, uwp, directx, direct2d, wrl

I am trying to follow Microsoft's official tutorial for [DirectX and XAML interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop) in order to make a C++ runtime library for image primitive drawing for a UWP application. However, the code is riddled with bugs and typos. I have managed to adapt portions of it, but I am getting runtime errors.

I have adapted the code as follows.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D> m_sisNativeWithD2D;

IInspectable* sisInspectable = (IInspectable*) reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(surfaceImageSource);
sisInspectable->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D), (void **)&m_sisNativeWithD2D);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device> m_d3dDevice;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> m_d3dContext;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Device> m_d2dDevice;

// Create the DXGI device
D3D11CreateDevice(
    NULL,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &m_d3dDevice,
    NULL,
    &m_d3dContext);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice;
m_d3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice);

// To enable multi-threaded access (optional)
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D10Multithread> d3dMultiThread;

m_d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D10Multithread), (void **)&d3dMultiThread);

d3dMultiThread->SetMultithreadProtected(TRUE);

// Create the D2D device
HRESULT d2d1 = D2D1CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), NULL, &m_d2dDevice);
```

While debugging the code, I can see that the `d2d1` handle is returning `E_INVALIDARG`. I tried passing device properties instead of `NULL` and disabling multi-threaded access, but the error persists. Objects before this line seem to be correctly initialized.

What could be causing this behavior?

### Edit

VTT's comment helped in constructing the device, but it seems that the device is not appropriate. My adapted code is as follows.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D> m_sisNativeWithD2D;

IInspectable* sisInspectable = (IInspectable*) reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(surfaceImageSource);
sisInspectable->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D), (void **)&m_sisNativeWithD2D);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device> m_d3dDevice;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> m_d3dContext;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Device> m_d2dDevice;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL array[] = {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
};

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL selectedFeatureLevel;

// Create the DXGI device
D3D11CreateDevice(
    NULL,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
    array,
    sizeof(array)/sizeof(D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &m_d3dDevice,
    &selectedFeatureLevel,
    &m_d3dContext);

//Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice;
//m_d3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIDevice> dxgiDevice;
auto hr = m_d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&dxgiDevice);

// To enable multi-threaded access (optional)
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D10Multithread> d3dMultiThread;
m_d3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D10Multithread), (void **)&d3dMultiThread);
d3dMultiThread->SetMultithreadProtected(TRUE);

// Create the D2D device
HRESULT d2d1 = D2D1CreateDevice(dxgiDevice.Get(), NULL, &m_d2dDevice);

// Set the D2D device
m_sisNativeWithD2D->SetDevice(m_d2dDevice.Get());

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext> drawingContext;

RECT rect;
rect.top = 0;
rect.left = 0;
rect.right = 50;
rect.bottom = 50;

POINT offset;

HRESULT beginDrawHR = m_sisNativeWithD2D->BeginDraw(rect, __uuidof(ID2D1DeviceContext), &drawingContext, &offset);
```

However, here the `BeginDraw()` method fails with `E_INVALIDARG`. I am assuming it is because of the incorrect device construction.

Comment: It looks like you are avoiding to pass reasonable values into `D3D11CreateDevice` constructor. For d2d compatibility you need to pass at least `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT` flag and appropriate feature_levels array. Also letting it auto select adapter is usually not a good idea, typically you want to use the adapter to which the target output belongs to.

Comment: @VTT I have created the object by passing the flags and feature levels array. The problem seems to be resolved, but I would like to pass the adapter to the constructor. How would you go about constructing the appropriate one? I tried to use the `IDXGIFactory` and enumerate adapters, but `m_d3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice);` fails with every one.

Comment: Does `m_sisNativeWithD2D->SetDevice` call succeed? Is surfaceImageSource already displayed when you call this code?

Comment: `SetDevice()` returns `S_OK`. The caller code is in C# and the `SurfaceImageSource` is assigned as source of an image component visible in the window.